# Please advise SQL Update issue

Tags: sql, select

I have a SQL database with two tables

**TableA** (`ID, State, Value`)

```
1 England  20   
2 France   50  
3 USA      40   
4 ........   
5 ........
```

and

**TableB** (`ID, username, age, stateID`)

```
1 John   15 1  
2 Adam   20 2  
3 Jane   40 3  
4 Scott  50 1    
5 Edwin  60 2   
6 Alex   20 3   
7 Olsen  30 1   
8 ...........   
9 ...........
```

What I need is to update `TableB` by setting the age for all users

- from `England` to be 20
- and from `France` to be 50

and so on...

Answer (score 3):

```
update tableB
set age = (select tableA.value from tableA where tableA.StateID=TableB.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like this form below:

```
update b set
    age = a.value
from tableB b
join tableA a on a.id = b.stateId
```

because you can write it this way (at last in SQL Server Management Studio):

```
update b set
    age = a.value
--select b.age, a.value, b.*, a.*
from tableB b
join tableA a on a.id = b.stateId
```

then highlight the part from `select ...` to the end of query and execute it (<kbd>F5</kbd>) to check what you are going to change (value before and after).